# Disable Azure AD MFA Interrupt Mode for a group of users

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-lab-services

I'm creating a set of hands-on lab users in my Azure AD for access to [Azure Labs](https://labs.azure.com). We will reuse these user accounts (and reset the passwords after every lab session).

My challenge is that these users are being required to configure MFA. Which I THINK is called the Azure AD Interrupt Mode described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-registration-mfa-sspr-combined).

Is there a way to exclude these group of users from being required to set this up?
[image]

Comment: So we found a way where we still configure the MFA details but use Conditional Access policies to exclude requiring MFA upon sign-in. It works, but we still have to set the MFA details for each lab user...

This workaround is quite a painful process esp since there seems to be no way to bulk update the MFA details (e-mail and phone number) via powershell.

I will share the details of this workaround if someone can confirm that this is the only way at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*// Answering my own question and hope it helps someone.*

The first and obvious step is to disable MFA. This is described in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates

After this, however, you may still face the interrupt wizard as shared in the screenshot of the question above. This is due to Self-Service Password Reset (SSPR) being enabled. If SSPR is enabled, then MFA is still required for them to be able to do a password reset.

**Solution 1: If you want SSPR enabled, then create a Conditional Access policy requiring MFA upon sign in.**

- This way, MFA is only triggered when user wants to do an SSPR.
- For this lab user scenario, you will still have to set-up MFA one-time for each of the users (you may use the same contact details).

Extra note: I tried setting the MFA details by bulk using PowerShell. However, it is not possible to set an MSOL user object's StrongAuthenticationUserDetails property.

**Solution 2: Disable SSPR or limit to selected users using AD groups**

- Don't include the lab users in the selected users group. Since SSPR is not allowed for these users, the extra MFA details won't be asked of these users anymore.
- Drawback: The setting is to ***include*** user groups which should have SSPR. There's no option to ***exclude*** just the lab users.

Solution 2 works for me but may not work for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be disabled entirely by navigating to Azure AD - Default Directory - Properties - Manage Security Defaults (right at the bottom of the page) - Enable Security Defaults - set it to No.

If it's per user basis, then Navigate to Azure AD - All users - Per User MFA - this will list all the users and then you can select "n" number of them to either enable or disable MFA.

Comment: Thanks Srinath. In my case, it was already disabled but was still being prompted with the above. Turns out it's because self-service password reset is enabled.