# Azure AD B2C MFA enforcement doesn't work

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

We want to have some users required to use MFA and some users that can log without. For this we have two groups "MFA Required" and "MFA Not Required". When we want to active MFA for a user, we simply move them from one group to the other.
We have a conditional access that enforces the MFA.

The includes/excludes:

[image]

The grant:

[image]

The User flow:

[image]

The issue is that now I get the MFA screen for all users. The "MFA Enforcement" even says "Conditional delegates the MFA decision to conditional access policies." when hovering above the "i". When I check the option "Enforce conditional access policies" in the User Flow nothing changes.

What is going on here? I feel I'm missing something, but I can't find anything online.

EDIT: I checked the audit logs in azure and when I log in with the user from "MFA Required" I see this:

[image]

And for the user from "MFA Not Required" I see this:

[image]

I still get the MFA screen for both though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RukminiMr-MT answer helped me gather a lot of information.

I had contacts with people from Microsoft and the thing is that when you use the Authenticator app as MFA option every user will have to register their authenticator app as MFA solution the next/first time they log in (after the change).

After they registered it for the first time they'll never get the MFA screen again. It's just a one time thing. The second time they log in, only the users from my MFA list get the MFA screen.

Check the date of this answer, since there are items in preview everything I just said might already have changed.

Answer (score 1):

***The reason behind getting MFA screen for all users may be due to below:***

- Check whether you have enabled **per-user MFA** to the users.

[image]

- Please **note** that, if you are conditional access policies you should not enable/enforce per-user Azure Ad MFA.
- If you have enabled that option, the user might get **MFA screen** even they are excluded via conditional access policies.
- Check whether you have enabled **security defaults** option. If enabled, make sure to disable it.

[image]

Please check whether **Self-Service Password Reset** is enabled. Make sure to disable it.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Enable per-user Multi-Factor Authentication - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates)

[Disable Azure AD MFA Interrupt Mode for a group of users - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69354861/disable-azure-ad-mfa-interrupt-mode-for-a-group-of-users%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Per-user MFA is disabled for all users, the security defaults are also disabled and the Self-Service Password reset was also turned off.

Comment: I just tested it all again but with "email" selected as the MFA method and it all seems to work. Maybe this was all because the Authenticator app method is in preview?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use an extra User Flow for login without MFA conditions set.

Requirements:

- UserFlow1 with ClientId1: with conditional MFA requirements (as shown in the first screenshot in this topic)
- UserFlow2 with ClientId2: without MFA (no enforcement and no conditional)
- Your application has a list of users with knowledge of MFA setting (yes/no)
- You need an inital login page (only contains e-mail address)

Steps to implement:

1. User enters e-mail address
2. check if MFA is required
   in your application
3. Redirect to UserFlow1 or UserFlow2 with
   login_hint=email@address.com in the url for convenience
4. Validate claims; the property
   tfp contains the flow used for log in, this must match the flow from
   step 2.

Update; you need two seperate app registrations with seperate ClientId's to get this working.